# MySQL query CASE WHEN THEN in UPDATE statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, case

I am trying to execute the following statement but it is resulting in error. There is not much to explain the situation here as the query itself is self explanatory. However, I will attach the error below:

Query

```
UPDATE swipes SET
CASE
    WHEN swp_from = :me AND swp_to = :user THEN first_swp = 'rewind'
    WHEN swp_to = :me AND swp_from = :user THEN second_swp = 'rewind'
END
```

Error

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN swp_from = '39' AND swp_to = '22' THEN f...' at line 2 in G:\xampp\htdocs\kelvie\processes\revoke.php on line 19
```

I know that the keywords `SET` and `CASE` cannot come together which is causing this error. But this is how the query needs to be framed. With this as an example can somebody guide me the proper way to frame the query to match the exact same expectation?

Comment: SQL is not a programming language and `CASE ... END` is not a flow control structure. You use it to build a value rather than branch statements.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, CASE has two usages: one as a flow control structure as the other as an expression: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html But your point is good, that one cannot use a flow control structure in the middle of a statement, as if it's an expression.

Comment: @BillKarwin Fair enough. It's confusing that MySQL doesn't have a name for its non-SQL language.

Comment: Both update and CASe is very wrong and don't follow the manual

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, MySQL's term is "compound statements": https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-compound-statements.html It is the SQL language. The ANSI/ISO SQL standard does specify a language for stored routines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UPDATE syntax, you must have `SET column = <expression>`. You can set multiple columns, but they must all be `column = <expression>`. You can't wrap the assignments in a CASE statement.

Here's how to write your UPDATE:

```
UPDATE swipes SET
  first_swp  = CASE WHEN swp_from = :me AND swp_to = :user THEN 'rewind'
                    ELSE first_swp END,
  second_swp = CASE WHEN swp_to = :me AND swp_from = :user THEN 'rewind' 
                    ELSE second_swp END;
```

The ELSE means if the condition is not true, then set `first_swp = first_swp`, i.e. no change.

You could also do this in two updates, which makes the code more clear and if the indexes support it, should run a lot more quickly because it won't have to examine every row.

```
START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE swipes SET first_swp = 'rewind'
WHERE swp_from = :me AND swp_to = :user;

UPDATE swipes SET second_swp = 'rewind'
WHERE swp_to = :me AND swp_from = :user;

COMMIT;
```

The transaction is to make sure both changes are committed or else neither.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot choose which column you want to update dynamically. The `case` has to be after the `=`

```
UPDATE swipes 
SET first_swp = CASE WHEN swp_from = :me AND swp_to = :user 
                     THEN 'rewind' 
                     ELSE first_swp 
                END,
   second_swp = CASE WHEN swp_to = :me AND swp_from = :user 
                     THEN 'rewind' 
                     ELSE second_swp 
                END
```